# Pyinstaller modulenotfound error: no module name 'mysql'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, mysql-python

I created an executable using pyinstaller. My scripts all run fine but when i run the executable i get the error below. It appears it doesnt like the mysql connector in DBconnection.py. Any help is appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in 
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_i
mporters.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "DBconnection.py", line 2, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[4780] Failed to execute script main

DBconnection.py:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection
import Global

def create_db_connection(filename= 'my.ini', section= 'dbconnection'):
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)

db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
    items = parser.items(section)
    for item in items:
        db[item[0]] = item[1]

else:
    raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section. filename))

#global conn
Global.conn = MySQLConnection(**db)
print(Global.conn)


def close_db_connection():
Global.conn.close()
```

main.py:

```
from servers import updateservers
from policies import updatepolicies
from updateguardpoints import updateguardpoints
from activities import updateactivities
from guardpointstatus import updateguardpointstatus
from application import updateapplication
from application_servers import updateapplication_servers
from DBconnection import create_db_connection
from DBconnection import close_db_connection
from TrouxConnection import TrouxConnection
from TrouxConnection import CloseTrouxConnection
import Global


create_db_connection()
TrouxConnection()
updateservers()
updatepolicies()
updateguardpoints()
updateactivities()
updateguardpointstatus()
updateapplication()
updateapplication_servers()
CloseTrouxConnection()
close_db_connection()
```

Comment: reinstalled mysql - connector using PIP. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

reinstalled mysql - connector using PIP. Issue resolved